# Transformers tokenizer batch encode a list of lists of strings

Tags: tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface-datasets

I have my dataset in the format of a list(A) of lists(B) of strings:

```
foo = [['asdf', 'hello', 'john matthew'],
       ['asdf', 'good bye', 'luke caleb'],
       ['asdf', 'see you tomorrow', 'peter simon']]
```

The intuition is that, B, an element in A represents a conversation. Then each element in B represents one utterance in the conversation.

I would like to use something along the lines like `batch_encode_plus` from [transformers tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer) to encode foo.

Currently I have my code like:

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', use_fast=True)
bar = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
            foo,
            return_tensors='pt',
            padding='max_length',
            truncation=True,
            max_length=50
        )
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]
```

However, when I looked up the documentation in [transformers tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer), it said that `typing.List[typing.List[str]]` is one of the types expected for the `batch_text_or_text_pairs` parameter in `batch_encode_plus`.

How should I go about this? I just want to tokenize my list of lists of strings. If batch_encode_plus isn't the way to go, is there another, more efficient way to do this?
I'm doing this as a part of a function with which I'll map a dataset (with content in the form of foo) that will go into a pytorch lightning data module to be fed into a model later on.

Thanks in advance.